# Boolean is not set correctly

Tags: lua

I was scripting today and stuck in a question.

Why when i use this:

```
local bool = false
function()
   bool = bool and false or true
end
```

If i call function two times, boolean are returning true both times instaed of returning true and false like i expected.

But if i use:

```
local bool = false
function()
   bool = not bool and true or false
end
```

This way the bool is set correctly to true and false.

Why its happening?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Operator precedence in Lua is `not` > `and` > `or`. This means your first expression is equivalent to `(bool and false) or true`. This will always be the same as `bool or true` which will always be `true`. Your second expression is equivalent to `((not bool) and true) or false` which is equivalent to `(not bool) or false` which is equivalent to `not bool`, which is clearly not the same as just `true`.

Thus your assumption that the two boolean expressions are equivalent is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`false and false or true` and `true and false or true` will always be `true`.

`true and true or false` will be `true`, and when called again, `false and true or false` will be `false`.

Regardless, there's really no reason for the end of that statement. If you're trying to toggle the boolean value, you could just use `bool = not bool`

Comment: Its not like i said. If we use: 

local bool = false
bool = bool and false or true
print(bool)
bool = bool and false or true
print(bool)

will print true 2x times..

but if we use:
local bool = false
bool = not bool and true or false
print(bool)
bool = not bool and true or false
print(bool)

will print true and false (correctly)

i need to use that way because i need to call a function two times and i set the bool inside this function. i justed wanted to know why the first method not print true and false, its the same like the second method.

Comment: ...and I told you why. It's not the same as the second method.